# HIVE ODBC - Failover

Tags: hadoop, hive, odbc, failover

In HIVE JDBC Driver - there are options to use Zookeper and multiple HS2 ip addresses to handle failover.

```
jdbc:hive2://zookeeper_quorum|hs2_host:port/[db][;principal=<hs2_principal>/<hs2_host>|_HOST@<KDC_REALM>][;transportMode=binary|http][;httpPath=<http_path>][;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=<zk_namespace>]
```

In HIVE ODBC, in the ODBC.ini file, below are the supported options -

```
[Hive]
Driver = <path_to_libodbchive.so>
Description = Hive Driver v1
DATABASE = default
HOST = <Hive_server_address>
PORT = <Hive_server_port>
```

Is there a way in which we can add multiple IP's here for failover? Does anyone know of the driver supports it?

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: Which Hive ODBC driver are you using (there are a few out there)?

Comment: I am using Cloudera's driver. But I can switch to other driver for better features.

Comment: I just did some checking, and none of the major Hive ODBC drivers support failover while specifying Hive servers, however they do support failover when specifying ZooKeeper endpoints.

Comment: Can you pls provide this solution to add zookeeper endpoints in odbc.ini file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See page 60 of http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/other/connectors/hive-odbc/latest/Cloudera-ODBC-Driver-for-Apache-Hive-Install-Guide.pdf for instructions on the `HOST` keyword, which lets you specify multiple ZooKeeper endpoints.